# Does anybody know that why C172S POH doesn't have normal & soft field landing distance chart?

Tags: landing, poh

Thank you for reading my writing.

I found out that C172S, C172P model POH doesn't have normal landing distance & soft field landing distance chart or table. It has only short field landing distance.

Does anybody know the reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Typically light GA aircraft do not list normal landing distances or soft field distances in AFMs.  Looking at the POH from a 172S

[image]

Look at Note 3, which refers to typical soft field conditions.  It indicates that a 45% increase in the short field figures is representative of soft field landing distances.

As a “normal” landing distances vary depending on how aggressive one applies stopping techniques on the ground this distance is going to vary depending on how the pilot flies the approach and landing.  Unless a specific procedure is described for this, as in the case for short field operations, there’s no way to draw up definitive performance tables for this.  In addition, the critical value here is if the pilot has enough runway available to fly the approach and stop the airplane in the minimum distance required.  If in doubt as to how much runway one will need during landing, the pilot should plan on using a short field procedure and use the published tables accordingly.

For general operations, I find an approximate 30% increase in the figures listed in these tables will provide a good margain for error and offer a conservative margain for landing figures.

Example: grass field, 4120 ft ASL, local altimeter setting of 29.83” Hg, 82° F (28°C), still air.

Pressure altitude is 4210 ft.

Using an E6B, the density altitude is 6,500 ft

Select 7000 ft from the table, 10°C column.

This gives a 730 ft landing roll from the table and 1585 ft distance to clear 50ft obstacle.

Increasing the ground roll figure by 45% for soft field gives 1059 ft ground roll and (1585-730) + 1059 = 1914 ft to clear 50 ft obstacle.

Increase by 30% for safety margin gives 1376 ft ground roll and 2488ft to clear 50ft obstacle.

Comment: But older airplane POHs have normal landing distance chart or table. I guess I need normal landing distance chart more than short field landing chart. Do you know why manufacturer stop publishing normal landing distance chart?

Comment: Which airplane specifically has a normal landing distances published?

Comment: @이준세 Because if you are concerned about the length of the field, you should be using the short-field technique. Also, don't land at a field you can't take-off from, the take-off distance is larger than the landing distance, so if you want a "normal landing distance" yard-stick, use the take-off distance chart.

Comment: @CarloFelicione - used to be very common.  Here is an example of a normal landing distance chart in a 1972 Cessna 172 (see page 6-5 at this link).http://www.joshwakefield.com/N3937Q/1972_C-172_Owners_Manual.pdf

Comment: Oh yes, the old manuals written in the days when many companies are not held legally liable for omissions like that.  No specification given for braking or stopping, etc.  As such the data is virtually useless.

Comment: Also, if you’re going to get a ground roll of 520ft at sea level on landing for a Cessna 172, that’s, by default, a short field procedure.  I have enough hours of PIC time in that airplane to know that.  I suspect back in those days it was conveyed to pilots by word of mouth from instructors that the data was to be interpreted as valid for a short field landing only.

Comment: Take a look at the numbers published from that old POH and look how close they match the numbers for a new model C172S short field landing performance in the table I posted above.  Again without a specified braking and stopping procedure, one person’s interpretation of a normal landing procedure varies quite a bit from another pilot’s.  It appears as though Cessna wrote the old tables intending pilots would use them for providing realistic figures for landings conducted using a short field technique only.  Also note the old tables just say “Landing” not “Normal Landing”.

Comment: Thank you Ron, Carlo, 757toga. Now I understood why POH has short field landing distance chart only. I am really really appreciate your precious answers. Thanks A LOT. Thanks.